# Why can't I recover the exact original homography matrix from a transformed vector?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, homography

I am implementing a part of this paper: [Optimizing Through Learned Errors for Accurate Sports Field Registration](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.08034.pdf).

I am training a neural network to, based on an image, estimate the coordinates of a given reference vector after transformation by a homography matrix H. The goal being the ability to generate the homography of an image of real-life broadcast onto a generic template. To do so, I am creating ground truths for each image (basically try and make the most accurate homography of the image I can, and then compute the transformation of the reference vector).

To check and see that this data is accurate, I recreate the homography with the reference vector and it's transformed vector, and verify if the resulting matrix is equal to my "ground truth" homography. I thought this would be a quick thing, but actually I can't seem to find why it does not work. Every value is the same, but the last row.

```
# ground truth homography from correspondences between image and template
H, _ = cv2.findHomography(registered_image_points, registered_template_points, cv2.RANSAC)

# computing transformation of a reference vector of points
transformed_vector = self.get_transform(H, self.REFERENCE_POINTS))


H
...

[[ 3.22e+02  1.69e+02  5.31e+02]
 [ 1.50e+02  1.13e+03  2.65e+02]
 [-2.69e-02  6.20e-01  1.00e+00]]
```

```
# generated homography from reference vector and it's transformation
h = kornia.geometry.get_perspective_transform(self.REFERENCE_POINTS, transformed_vector)

h
...

[[ 3.22e+02  1.69e+02  5.31e+02]
 [ 1.50e+02  1.13e+03  2.65e+02]
 [-2.98e-07  4.47e-07  1.00e+00]
```

The reference vector is supposed to be from a a normalized image coordinate system (x,y) = [-0.5;0.5]. The template from a coordinate system (x,y) = [0;640].

This discrepancy makes it so that even with an accurate neural network that can give a perfect regression of the transformed vector, it wouldn't matter because I can't recover the ground truth and I don't know why.